# run nuxt3 with docker

Tags: docker, nuxtjs3

I build my Nuxt3 Applcation with this command which generates everything in a Folder `.output`:

`npm run build`

This is the DockerFile that I'm using to build the docker file:

```
FROM node:17-alpine3.14

ADD .output /webapp/.output

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /webapp/.output

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/webapp/.output/server/index.mjs"]
```

and `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  app-web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

everything runs without any errors but I expected to see the application by entering the address `http://localhost:3000` but nothing happens.

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: exec to your container and try to curl your application from there, if it's working then you might need to check your ports.

Comment: @Mayur this is not the Problem. The Request returns the error "document is empty"

Answer (score 2):

here is the working version:

```
FROM node:17-alpine3.14

ADD .output /webapp/.output

EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /webapp/.output

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD ["node", "/webapp/.output/server/index.mjs"]
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

Docker Compose (for development)

```
version: '3'
services:

  web-app:
    image: node:17-alpine
    container_name: web-app
    command: [sh, -c, "npm i && npm run dev"]
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    working_dir: '/webapp'
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - './:/webapp/'
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 3000
```

Docker (production)

```
FROM node:17-alpine

ENV HOST='0.0.0.0'
ENV PORT='3000'

WORKDIR /webapp

COPY ./ /webapp

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

DockerFile

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app

COPY .output/ /app

CMD ["node", "server/index.mjs"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  my-nuxt-app:
    build: .
    image: my-nuxt
    container_name: my-nuxt-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  my-nuxt-app2:
    build: .
    image: my-nuxt
    container_name: my-nuxt-app2
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
```

That's all you need

To use first an `npm run buid` after that a docker `build -t my-nuxt .`

In the file `docker-compose.yml` I can run `docker compose up -d` to run two containers of the same application. one running on port 3000 and the other on port 3001

Answer (score 0):

This is the Dockerfile we use to run our nuxt3 setup!

```
# see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG NODE_VERSION=node:16.14.2

FROM $NODE_VERSION AS dependency-base

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci

FROM dependency-base AS production-base

# build will also take care of building
# if necessary
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM $NODE_VERSION-slim AS production

COPY --from=production-base /app/.output /app/.output

# Service hostname
ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0

# Service version
ARG NUXT_APP_VERSION
ENV NUXT_APP_VERSION=${NUXT_APP_VERSION}

# Run in production mode
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# start the app
CMD [ "node", "/app/.output/server/index.mjs" ]
```

You can find an example here: https://github.com/sidestream-tech/sidebase/blob/main/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

This is the Dockerfile I have created.

[Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/ruyut/6d3fcfafdb8e497b73ce63036f74d1aa)

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# customize port 80
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["sh", "-c", "NITRO_PORT=80 node .output/server/index.mjs"]

# default port 3000
# EXPOSE 3000
# CMD ["node", ".output/server/index.mjs"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach relies on a build pipeline or the developer to generate or build the final output first. This method ensures the docker container is smaller and very quick to publish. The drawback is that the developer must run `yarn run build` or the equivalent `npm run build` before building the docker container--every time there are changes.

Again, this reduced the size of my docker container, which had a final layer that was over 1GB, to a final layer of about 5MB. Pushing the docker container is instant.

> Firrst, run `yarn run build` or `npm run build`

```
FROM node:18-alpine

COPY [".output", "."]

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

EXPOSE 3000 

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server/index.mjs"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Have two separate images one running node and another running nginx for static content.

## How-to

Set up a Nginx proxy that would host the static content more efficiently and have the nuxt service run on a separate container but only handle calls that are not handled by the static content.

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS ci

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./ ./

FROM ci AS build
RUN npm run build

FROM ci AS build-static
RUN npx nuxi generate

FROM build as build-static

RUN npx nuxi generate

FROM nginx:alpine as static

COPY --from=build-static /app/.output/public/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

FROM node:lts-alpine

ENV HOST='0.0.0.0'
ENV PORT='3000'
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/.output /app/.output
CMD [ "node", ".output/server/index.mjs" ]
```

The nginx default.conf would be overridden to route unhandled files back to the backend.

```
upstream backend {
    server nuxt-backend:3000;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location /p-sw.js {
        try_files $uri @backend;
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires off;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # Cache requests to _ipx to prevent constant regeneration
    location /_ipx {
        proxy_cache ipx;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 30m;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
        proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;
        proxy_pass http://backend/_ipx;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

This also makes the assumption that my other question [Does the IPX nuxt-img provider store the generated files somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241684/does-the-ipx-nuxt-img-provider-store-the-generated-files-somewhere) would be answered as "no it does not cache"