# Does the IPX nuxt-img provider store the generated files somewhere?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

When using `nuxt-img` does it cache the result of the conversion somewhere or is it always performed?

It looks like it's always peformed, Waterfox which does not support WEBP renders things properly but using a Chromium browser that supports WEBP I notice it gets stuck trying to rendering images.